# pvefindaddr p2 in mona?

Tags: exploit, shellcode, exploit-development, debugging

Is there a "!pvefindaddr p2" (search for all pop/pop/ret combinations in the entire process memory space) equivalent in mona.py?

Alternatively, is there any option to run pvefindaddr in latest versions of Immunity Debugger? Currently, when I'm trying to execute pvefindaddr following error is triggered:

```
Error
---------------------------
pycommands: failed to execute script.

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Immunity Inc\Immunity Debugger\PyCommands\pvefindaddr.py", line 1997, in main
    imm.Log("")
 AttributeError: 'Debugger' object has no attribute 'Log'

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Immunity debugger is abandoned software, I would recommend using mona under windbg instead (https://github.com/corelan/windbglib). You can use `!mona seh` or the `a` command (https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/07/14/mona-py-the-manual/) to search for your gadget.